# Validate text in TextField

Tags: cocoa, binding, refresh, validation, textfield

I have in my program a textfield which represents a fileName from a model object using bindings. I want that this textField could be used to enter a new fileName and after user presses Enter it should send the message to my model object that value of fileName has changed in my textField, then inside my model object the method for checking if such filename can be used is called. And if it returns true, then it should apply new value to my model object, if not, then value in my textField should undo to initial value.

Does somebody know how it could be implemented? I can validate my value but I can't make my textField refresh to initial value. As for both changing the model object value, and texField refreshing should be used single method which is KVC compliant I don't know how to implement such behaviour.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Does the method checking the fileName checking for invalid characters or making sure the filename is unique?  For example, not a duplicate.

Comment: It is checking if the name is unique...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a good UX to me; as a user, I would be upset to find that if I made a simple typo in a text field, it completely erased what I had just input. It would be *much* better to show a message indicating what was wrong and how the user can fix it. Nonetheless...

I think you should set up a text field delegate. Have the delegate keep a variable holding the last valid string that was input. Then in `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`, do your check for validity, and if the check does not pass, set the text field's value to that variable and return NO. If it does pass, change the variable to hold the new valid string and return YES.

Comment: You are right about showing the error message, but that are details. I didn't know how just to put this checking inside binding. Idea about delegate sounds good, but I'm not very familiar with them. Actually value from textField is bind to an object in array, so textField is bind to arrayController.selection.fileName. using delegate makes me to coordinate my binding programmatically, do I understand it correctly?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem combining delegate methods with bindings. Generally, delegate methods are ways to slightly customize the behavior of a class (often a UI element) without having to bother with subclassing. The idea is that the object asks its delegate for permission or feedback on various actions, so that you can, for example, stop a user from tabbing out of a text field if the input is not useful.

Comment: That sounds interesting. I'll study more about delegates to use it. Thank you for help...

Comment: Sure thing, good luck! BTW, Apple's conceptual documentation has a [writeup about delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18).